# Excluir clase java con spotbugs

Tags: java

Estoy intentado excluir todas las clases que contengan _ pero no consigo encontrar la expresión regular para que funcione.

Estoy probando con:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Class name="~*_"/>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular que tienes no es correcta, si quieres nombres que no contengan `_` podrías probar con algo como

```
^((?!_).)*$
```

Puedes probar [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/QCoszO/1)

Comment: gracias, al final encontré otra solución.